# Rundeck NodesetEmptyException: No matched nodes

Tags: rundeck

Unfortunately, **occassionally** we receive a following Rundeck exception for some of the scheduled jobs:

```
com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.NodesetEmptyException: No matched nodes: NodeSet{includes={name= myrealhost.com, dominant=false, }}
        at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.NodeFirstWorkflowExecutor.validateNodeSet(NodeFirstWorkflowExecutor.java:369)
        at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.NodeFirstWorkflowExecutor.executeWorkflowImpl(NodeFirstWorkflowExecutor.java:90)
        at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.workflow.BaseWorkflowExecutor.executeWorkflow(BaseWorkflowExecutor.java:222)
        at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.WorkflowExecutionServiceThread.runWorkflow(WorkflowExecutionServiceThread.java:83)
        at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.logging.LoggingManagerImpl$MyPluginLoggingManager.runWith(LoggingManagerImpl.java:148)
        at com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.execution.WorkflowExecutionServiceThread.run(WorkflowExecutionServiceThread.java:74)
Exception: class com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.NodesetEmptyException: No matched nodes: NodeSet{includes={name= myrealhost.com, dominant=false, }}
No matched nodes: NodeSet{includes={name=myrealhost.com, dominant=false, }}
```

While hunting for a solution online, I came across a relevant Github issue https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/2942#issuecomment-360573113. Unfortunately, the fix suggested didn't help.

Please note the following details for your reference:

```
Rundeck version: 3.1.0-20190731
DB Type: MySQL 8
Install type: war 
OS: Ubuntu 18
Use Asynchronous Cache: True
Cache Delay: 3600
Synchronous First Load: Enabled
Inventory source: Ansible Dynamic Inventory -- a Python script to load data from EtcD
```

Another relevant Github issue: https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/4231

Also, I haven't noticed any errors from Python inventory script except the aforementioned exception in Rundeck job log.

I had no choice but to reach out to the Rundeck community at Stack Overflow as the relevant Github issues seemed dormant.

I will appreciate any help on this front.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

It seems a node cache problem that happens sometimes. You can try [this](https://github.com/rundeck/rundeck/issues/2942#issuecomment-360573113) workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @megadrive68k. Unfortunately, I too came across the Github thread and tried the same but it didn't help. You may see that I've posted the Github link in my question.